# When hiding content make the divs jump smoother

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I created code that will remove a div and will animate the content inside of it to make it look like its sliding out. This is all going okay, but the divs underneath seem to jump up and I want to smooth this.
This is my code:

```js
$(document).on('click', 'div', function() {
  const span = $(this).find('span');
  const div = $(this);
  span.css({
    'right': '100%'
  });
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    div.hide();
  }, 250);
})
```

```css
div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 5em;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

div>span {
  right: 50%;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <span>
    one
  </span>
</div>
<div>
  <span>
    two
  </span>
</div>
<div>
  <span>
    three
  </span>
</div>
<div>
  <span>
    four
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

USe the [`slideUp`](https://api.jquery.com/slideUp/) method of jQuery along with a duration argument

```js
$(document).on('click', 'div', function() {
  const span = $(this).find('span');
  const div = $(this);
  span.css({
    'right': '100%'
  });
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    div.animate({height: 0, padding: 0}, 250);
  }, 250);
})
```

```css
div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 5em;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

div>span {
  right: 50%;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <span>
    one
  </span>
</div>
<div>
  <span>
    two
  </span>
</div>
<div>
  <span>
    three
  </span>
</div>
<div>
  <span>
    four
  </span>
</div>
```

There is a slight annoyance with the margins being animated with `slideUp` which make the gap between boxes smaller whilst animating. To prevent this, only animate the height and the padding.

```js
$(document).on('click', 'div', function() {
  const span = $(this).find('span');
  const div = $(this);
  span.css({
    'right': '100%'
  });
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    div.animate({height: 0, padding: 0}, 250)
    .animate({margin: 0}, 50);
  }, 250);
})
```

```css
div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 5em;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

div>span {
  right: 50%;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <span>
    one
  </span>
</div>
<div>
  <span>
    two
  </span>
</div>
<div>
  <span>
    three
  </span>
</div>
<div>
  <span>
    four
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Welp, I was looking too much into this that I even forgot about the slideUp() function. Thanks, this works!

Answer (score 0):

You just can add value to hide function. it also gives a smooth transition.

```js
$(document).on('click', 'div', function() {
  const span = $(this).find('span');
  const div = $(this);
  span.css({
    'right': '100%','height':'0px','transition':'5s'
  });
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    div.hide(500);
  }, 250);
})
```

```css
div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 5em;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

div>span {
  right: 50%;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all .25s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <span>
    one
  </span>
</div>
<div>
  <span>
    two
  </span>
</div>
<div>
  <span>
    three
  </span>
</div>
<div>
  <span>
    four
  </span>
</div>
```